# Is there a manifest for abstract types like there is for parameterized types?

Tags: scala, manifest, abstract-type

I wonder if you could write something like the following in Scala:

```
abstract class Foo

trait Bar {

  type Foo_Tpe <: Foo : Manifest[Foo_Tpe]

  def fooClass = classOf[Foo_Tpe]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can do this:

```
val man = manifest[Foo_Tpe]
```

At which point it will tell you it doesn't have a manifest for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can ask a subclass to provide it:

```
trait Bar {

  type Foo_Tpe <: Foo

  protected def fooManifest: Manifest[Foo_Tpe]

  def fooClass = fooManifest.erasure

}
```

Comment: I want to have that provided by the Scala compiler and not defined by a subtype.

Comment: You can't have it provided by the compiler from within `Bar`.